# Error when display data with conditions cakePHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, cakephp

I have database table named `SubjectTutor` and `Topic`. I want to display topic list that has same `school_id` and `subject_id`. `subject_id` decoded from json. but i dont have `school_id`, so i want to take `school_id` from `SubjectTutor` table. I am using cakephp.

The problem is:

> Data will not displayed or No record found but i have data on database. But if i change $school_id = $this->SubjectTutor->find('**first**',array('fields'=>array('school_id'),'conditions'=>array('SubjectTutor.tutor_id'=>$tutor_id)));
>
> then data will be displayed but not all data.

this is print_r($value):

```
Array ( [SubjectTutor] => Array ( [school_id] => 452 ) ) Array ( [SubjectTutor] => Array ( [school_id] => 453 ) ) Array ( [SubjectTutor] => Array ( [school_id] => 454 ) ) Array ( [SubjectTutor] => Array ( [school_id] => 67 ) )
```

this is the WebServicesController.php:

```
$school_id = $this->SubjectTutor->find('all',array('fields'=>array('school_id'),'conditions'=>array('SubjectTutor.tutor_id'=>$tutor_id)));
foreach ($school_id as $key => $value)
{
print_r($value);
$all_topics = $this->Topic->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Topic.subject_id'=>$decoded['subject_id'],'Topic.school_id'=>$value['SubjectTutor']['school_id']),'order'=>'Topic.name ASC'/* ,'limit'=>$limit,'offset'=>$offset */));
}
```

Please help i really confuse.

Comment: what is this: `Array ( [SubjectTutor] => Array ( [school_id] => 452 ) ) Array ( [SubjectTutor] => Array ( [school_id] => 453 ) ) Array ( [SubjectTutor] => Array ( [school_id] => 454 ) ) Array ( [SubjectTutor] => Array ( [school_id] => 67 ) ) `  ?

Comment: that is the print_r($value). the value of $school_id.

Comment: You haven't explained your problem clearly. Which code is printing **school_id: 67** ?

Comment: i have edited the question, please review @Sam

Answer (score 0):

This statement has no problem
 `$school_id = $this->SubjectTutor->find('all',array('fields'=>array('school_id'),'conditions'=>array('SubjectTutor.tutor_id'=>$tutor_id)));`. If you are not getting all the data then it might be the problem with your tables mapping/Data. 
 This query `$school_id = $this->SubjectTutor->find('first',array('fields'=>array('school_id'),'conditions'=>array('SubjectTutor.tutor_id'=>$tutor_id)));` returns the first result matching the where condition. You can read more about fetching data from database in cakephp 3 [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html) and cakephp 2 [here](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html). 
 
 **P.S. Describe your problem clearly and what you did on your own to solve the problem. What you want and what you are getting must be propely explained.**